# Getting wrong output after calling an overriden method in C++

Tags: c++

I am making a program that contains base class RentedVehicle and its derived class FuelVehicle and the derived class of FuelVehicle as Car class. My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class RentedVehicle {
private:
    double baseFee;
public:
    RentedVehicle() {};
    RentedVehicle(int a): baseFee(a) {
    };

    virtual double getCost() {
        return baseFee;
    }

};

class FuelVehicle: public RentedVehicle {
private:
    double kms;
public:
    int mileageFees = 0;
    FuelVehicle() {};
    FuelVehicle(double a, int b): RentedVehicle(a) {
        kms = b;
    };

    double getMileageFees() {

        if (kms < 100) {
            mileageFees = 0.2*kms;
        } else if (kms >= 100 && kms <= 400) {
            mileageFees = 0.3*kms;
        } else if (kms > 400) {
            double x = (kms - 400);
            mileageFees = (0.3*kms) + (0.5*x);
        }
        return mileageFees;
    }

    double getKms() {
        return kms;
    }
};

class Car: public FuelVehicle {
private:
    int seats;
public:
    Car() {};
    Car(int a, double b, double c):  FuelVehicle(b, c) {
        seats = a;
    };
    double bF = getCost();
    double mF = getMileageFees();
    double getCost() {
        double cost = mF + (bF*seats);
        return cost;
    }
    int getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }
};


int main() {
    Car c1(5, 500, 20);
    double y = c1.getCost();
    cout << "cost is: " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm calling overriden getCost() method it's showing **cost is: 4**. However a/c to my given parameters the cost should be **2504**.
What is the mistake?

Comment: The mistake here is not using a debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and see how the program executes. This is something that can be easily figured out in any debugger. Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: No I don't know how to use it

Comment: Well, you should learn how to use it. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. What do you think makes more sense: learning how to use a debugger, so you can figure out and fix bugs in your code, every time, in maybe a few minutes; or asking for help on a web site every time you can't figure out why your program doesn't work, and then wait hours, or even days, to see if anyone answers?

Comment: `double bF = getCost();` ... but `getCost()` uses `bF`.

Comment: @overhaul_ -- Learning how to debug your own programs is part and parcel in learning how to write programs.  It's not simply write a program, compile it, run it, and then go to StackOverflow to fix the problems.

Comment: Side note: Sometimes it's a good idea to have a default constructor that does nothing, but in the case of `RentedVehicle`, there is no way to set `baseFee` other than the `RentedVehicle(int a): baseFee(a) {};` constructor. `RentedVehicle() {};` allows objects containing an invalid and unchangeable `baseFee`.

Comment: You don’t need a debugger to discover that the value of `bF` depends on the value of `bF`, which is not a good idea.

Comment: `RentedVehicle() {};` - no - better: `RentedVehicle() = default;`. *If* a default constructor is what you really want.

Comment: Consider giving your variables and parameters more meaningful names. a, b, c don't give any clue what those are making it very easy to mix them up when you use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
double bF = getCost();
```

in the `Car` class, you are calling the most derived version of `getCost`. But this function:

```
double getCost() {
        double cost = mF + (bF*seats);
        return cost;
    }
```

will invoke undefined behavior since you are using `bF` in this function before it's initialized.

Instead, you can use the base class version of `getCost`, like this:

```
double bF = FuelVehicle::getCost();
```

which prints the expected value of 2504.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GPMnEb).

Answer (score 2):

1- Proper use of variables is missing. bf is used before initialization. Use the scope resolution operator to clarify the code and avoid ambiguity. When you called getcost() function of the base class, it finds the function in the existing class and binds it with the caller which causes ambiguity.

2- Tip: Try to implement OOP principles more accurately. You could have made getcost() function a pure virtual function instead of a simple virtual function. The pure virtual function gives more authentication to code. In your case, the getcost() function should be made a necessary requirement for any class that derives from Rented class as the cost is an essential part of it and defining it must be made a requirement of code. This can be achieved by making get-cost() a pure virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the class like this:

```
class Car: public FuelVehicle {
private:
    int seats;
public:
    Car() {};
    Car(int a, double b, double c):  FuelVehicle(b, c) {
        seats = a;
    };
    double bF = getCost();
    double mF = getMileageFees();
```

Is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
 private:
    int    seats;
 public:
    double bF;
    double mF;
    Car()
        : FuelVehicle()          // Call to default constructor of base
        // , seats               => Not initialized
        , bF(getCost())          // uses mF but that is not initialized yet.
                                 // uses bF but that is not initialized yet.
                                 // uses seats but that is not initialized yet.
                                 // Accessing uninitialized variables is UB
        , mF(getMileageFees())   // Calls the base class
                                 // But this was default initialized (see above)
                                 // The default constructor does not initialize
                                 // the member variables so this will
                                 // probably return some random value but
                                 // is technically UB.
    {};
    Car(int a, double b, double c)
        : FuelVehicle(b, c)
        // , seats               => Not initialized
        , bF(getCost())          // uses mF but that is not initialized yet.
                                 // uses bF but that is not initialized yet.
                                 // uses seats but that is not initialized yet.
                                 // Accessing uninitialized variables is UB

        , mF(getMileageFees())   // This is OK as the base class was
                                 // initialized correctly.
    {
        seats = a;               // Assignment to seats which defines it
                                 // But it is already used above.
    };
```